# ResolveUrl Problem in Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, resolveurl

Okay,

I know it is weird but when I put this code between `<head runat="server"></head>` in master.page, this is how it renders into:

```
 <link id="ctl00_Link1" rel="shortcut icon" href="../%3C%25%20ResolveUrl(%22~/Resources/Pictures/Shared/Misc/favicon.ico%22);%20%25%3E" type="image/x-icon" />
```

It doesn't see something asp.net needs to take care of.

This is the original code :

```
<link id="Link1" rel="shortcut icon" href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Resources/Pictures/Shared/Misc/favicon.ico") %>' type="image/x-icon" runat="server" />
```

Basically Asp.Net doesn't take care of the code below and renders as a normal html.

How can I get over this problem?

Thanks in advance...

**Edit and Resolved**

Okay people, there is no way for doing this. I've finally figured out because ResolveUrl or ResolveClientUrl is only working for these below :

```
@import '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Resources/Styles/MainMaster/MainDesign.css") %>';
<script src='Resources/Scripts/Libraries/jquery-1.4.2.js' type="text/javascript"</script>
```

it is too literal for link so you need to put link elements in body tag like :

```
<body>
    <link id="iconOne" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Resources/Pictures/Shared/Misc/favicon.ico"/>
    <link id="iconTwo" rel="icon" href='Resources/Pictures/Shared/Misc/favicon.ico' type="image/ico" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the reason you ran into your first issue was because the link tag had `runat="server"` This tells asp.net to treat it as a server control, rather then a literal. Because its a server control, your scriptlet tag (`<%= %>`) isn't really doing anything, since its a server control property it is treating it as literal text.

There are two ways to handle it. First is to [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx) to register a startup script. This will put your link tag inside the body, which is the way microsoft says you should do it, but aesthetically isn't that nice. The other option is to do something like this in your Page_Load

```
var link = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "shortcut icon");
link.Attributes.Add("src", ResolveUrl("~/Resources/Pictures/Shared/Misc/favicon.ico"));
link.Attributes.Add("type", "image/x-icon");

Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

This builds out a control programatically, then adds it to the controls collection on the head, which will render as what you want at the end of the head tag. Problem with this is that its a bit more work, and its better to avoid monkeying with control collections at the code behind level if you can get away with it.

Comment: I tried the second one already but it didn't change anything. Control renderer rendered it the way it wants eventually. And yeah I just put the link element under the `<body>` tag and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

That might be making it a little more complicated than it needs to be. Have you tried simply using `~` in icon path, and setting `<head runat="server">`?

For example:

```
<head runat="server">
    ...
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Resources/Pictures/Shared/Misc/favicon.ico" 
        type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Resources/Pictures/Shared/Misc/favicon.ico"
        type="image/x-icon" />
    ...
</head>
```

*Related SO answer*: [Favicon Not Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296038/favicon-not-showing)