# Favicon Not Showing

Tags: asp.net, html, favicon

I have a favicon in my ASP.NET project that's not showing up. I have a masterpage located at ~/MasterPages/MasterPage.master that holds the favicon. My markup is as follows:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

The favicon is located in the project root. The dimensions are 16x16 and it's 32-bit depth.  I've cleared my browser's cache, rebooted and nothing is working. Any suggestions as to what I should do?

Comment: Could it be the file is not being accessed properly?  Depending on the file structure, you may not need the `/` in front of favicon.ico.

Comment: Are you able to navigate directly to the favicon.ico file in the browser? i.e `http://projectroot/favicon.ico`?

Comment: When I hit the favicon directly, I get this error in Chrome:

This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://root/login.aspx?returnurl=%2ffavicon.ico has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: ctrl f5 is doing the trick for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try placing a `~` and set the `link` elements to `runat=server`

```
<link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link runat="server" rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

This also needs to be done in the `<head>` section of the page.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the `~` on `<link>` tag works even without `runat="server"`

Comment: @BrunoLM -   ~ requires a virtual path mapping, hence needs to run in managed code to interpret the virtual path of the site.

Comment: Adding the tilde '`' and runat="server" attributes fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: What if my current page is in a folder? The ~ path will be resolved to http://example.com/Myfolder/favicon.ico

Comment: Made these changes to the lines I got from realfavicongenerator.net and that solved all my issues. (using MVC asp.net)

Comment: Referencing the assets in the `<head>` tag was the critical part here.  Easy to forget to do this because most guides leave that out, and an asp.net site will generally have the head tag contained within a `_Layout.cshtml` partial.

Answer (score 10):

Try to leave the type away, clear the browser cache and go to the favicon address manually and add some parameters to it. That should fix it. Maybe you could tell me your website address, then I will look, if it shows up here.

Comment: "add some parameters to it" saved my day

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the solution and go to Properties. Under Application > Resources change the default icon to your chosen one.

Answer (score 4):

Load up fiddler 
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
and look for the request from the browser for it - that will show you if its successful, a cache issue, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In a .NET Core app (MVC template) try moving the favicon.ico file to the lib folder instead of the wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this problem by renaming favicon.ico to myicon.ico, and reference it in the head `<link rel="icon" href="~/myicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Answer (score 1):

I used this method in ASP.NET:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="~/favicon.png">
```