# inconsistency between user controls and master page

Tags: asp.net, .net, user-controls, master-pages

I am using asp.NET with masterpages and usercontrols.

**In MasterPage:**

Doing

```
<link href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/path/file.css")%>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

will not work and the css will not load
BUT

Doing

```
<link runat="server" href='~/path/file.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

will work and the css will load

**In User Control:**

Doing

```
<link runat="server" href='~/path/file.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

will not work and the css will not load

BUT

Doing

```
<link href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/path/file.css")%>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

will work and the css will load

In master page ResolveUrl doesn't work and runat="server" works where in user control the opposite is the true. Maybe I worng and I appriciate if someone will check this. If this is the situation, what is the reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588740/resolveurl-problem-in-master-page

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Please read the question! ~ works in masterpage and ResolveUrl doesn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.
In one of the cases I had `<head runat="server">` tag. Because the runat="server", the ResolveUrl is not act as a server method but a simple text. That is why ResolveUrl didn't word - I had runat="server" in the head  tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath) in details what is going on.

In short is so the '~' character is only for use at the server

Comment: Please read the question! ~ works in masterpage and ResolveUrl doesn't!

Comment: What is the output if you do <link href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/path/file.css")%>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> at the masterpage and a normal page?

Comment: ResolveUrl fot <link /> tag in master page doesn't work and it doesn't give the path.

Comment: Try this <link href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/path/file.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />